# Alternative to ColorDrawable

Tags: android

I have a piece of code that extends ColorDrawable and calls the super with Color.Black. Is there an alternative where i can use a drawable  from my drawables directory ?

```
//Want to Have a drawable/res instead of just a plain Color type ? 
static class DownloadedDrawable extends ColorDrawable {

    public DownloadedDrawable(Color color) {
        super(color);

    }

    // Other code,
}
```

Kind Regards,

Comment: If you want a `Drawable` that's *not* a `ColorDrawable` then you shouldn't subclass from `ColorDrawable` in the first place. Maybe you can explain your broader scenario.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/source/checkout. I use this Library in my code. This sets a Drawable to a ImageView and wraps a AsyncTask in it. I want my own drwable instead of the simple black color while a ImageView is been processed.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a library; it's just an example project but if you want to have an image instead of just black, try deriving from [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) instead of from `ColorDrawable`. You can pass in the desired `Bitmap`.

Comment: So how do i use the drawable like the Color.Black.