# How to use BitmapDrawable's constructor/ Making a temporary load image?

Tags: android, android-drawable

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) it says this

> BitmapDrawable()
>   This constructor was deprecated in API level 4. Use BitmapDrawable(android.content.res.Resources, android.graphics.Bitmap) instead to specify a bitmap to draw with and ensure the correct density is set.

I'm trying to set a temporary image Before an image is loaded. To get to this point I used [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) tutorial which gave me this function to get a color temporary instead of an image using this function :

```
static class DownloadedDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
    private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

    public DownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
        super(Color.BLACK);
        bitmapDownloaderTaskReference =
            new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
    }

    public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
        return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
    }
}
```

I got to the idea to use the `BitmapDrawable` by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693799/alternative-to-colordrawable) question 
If you know another way to do this I will of course be happy to use it but I prefer not to use a lib.

Comment: there are dozens of options, for example LevelListDrawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a bitmap instead of a solid colour, extend from BitmapDrawable:

```
static class DownloadedDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

public DownloadedDrawable(Resources resources, Bitmap bitmap, BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
    super(resources, bitmap);
    bitmapDownloaderTaskReference =
        new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
}

public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
    return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
}
}
```

To use it:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable);
DownloadedDrawable draw = new DownloadedDrawable(getResources(), bitmap, yourBitmapDownloaderTask);
yourImageView.setImageDrawable(draw);
```

Comment: the function says that `The constructor BitmapDrawable(Resources, Drawable) is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

try to use `new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), canvasBitmap);`

Comment: I think I just don't really understand the method since this sets a color and I want it to be a image so that simple line can't help me as  I don't know where to place it.